# How to count array in foreach

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach

My Code is :

```
foreach ($suratmasuk as $key => $h) {
  $suratkeluar = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM surat_masuk WHERE lampiran LIKE '%$h->surat_id%'")->row_array()['suratmasuk_id'];
  echo count($suratkeluar);
}
```

The result is :

```
11
```

But i want the result is :

```
2
```

Because there are two data in the array. How is it? Pls help me

Comment: Is this a shell question?  Please add the relevant tag...

Comment: Which array are you talking about when you say *there are two data in the array*?

Comment: @NigelRen the variable $suratkeluar

Comment: So in the foreach there are 2 data and i want the result is 2 not 11.

Comment: I mistakenly remove the `codeigniter` tag. Please add it again by replacing `arrays` (`foreach` already there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `echo count($suratkeluar);` out of the loop. Now you create an array for each iteration and count the elements of that array. So the result is `1` and `1` -----> `11`

Try following

```
$suratkeluar = array();
foreach ($suratmasuk as $key => $h) {
  $suratkeluar[] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM surat_masuk WHERE lampiran LIKE '%$h->surat_id%'")->row_array()['suratmasuk_id'];
}
echo count($suratkeluar);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

If you return data object you need to make this

> echo count( array() $suratkeluar );

count() not working with data object